# How can I chain filters in CUPS

Tags: filter, cups

I created a file in */usr/lib/cups/filter/myCustomFilter* and put same owner, group and permissions as the other filters. But i can't apply my filter in *printer.ppd*.
I don't want substitute existent filter, only execute some script before printing. How can i do this ?

Comment: Have you added a line similar to  `*cupsFilter: "text/plain 0 myCustomFilter"` in your pod file ?